# How edit File to MyFile

Tags: java, extends

I have a program, it uses a standard class File.
The ArrayList.
I need to replace your class MyFile and really want to change the collection ArrayList to List .

class MyFile

```
public class MyFile extends File {

    public MyFile(File f) {
        super(f, "");
    }

    Boolean isNetworkFile = false;



}
```

example function in programm

```
public void addFile(JFrame frame) {
    FileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    FileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    FileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    int fileValid = FileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
    if (fileValid == javax.swing.JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        return;
    }
    else if(fileValid == javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File[] file = FileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
        listSong.addAll(Arrays.asList(file));
    }
}
```

How do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to replace your class MyFile and really want to change the collection ArrayList to List."? Your question currently doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand.  But I'll take a guess at what you mean.  It looks like you'll need a loop, to construct `MyFile` instances from `File` instances:

```
File[] files = FileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
MyFile[] myfiles = new MyFile[files.length];
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    myfiles[i] = new MyFile(files[i]);
}
```

As for the collection, an `ArrayList` **is** a `List`.  You can just do:

```
List<Blah> list = new ArrayList<Blah>();
```